# Move lines connect divs when divs dragged

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, canvas, drag-and-drop

I currently have these lines drawn to connect these div tags here: http://sandbox.brightboxstudios.com/orgmap/index2.html

However when the divs are dragged the lines to not follow..

How can I keep the lines connected? Thanks!!

Resource found and am not sure how to implement:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#event-drag

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a updateCanvas callback to your draggable call, like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blk").draggable(
        {drag: function() {updateCanvas($("#canvas"), $(".blk"));}}   
    );
});
```